# Dynamically built word document (.docx) is corrupt when saved and opened from an asp.net page

Tags: asp.net-mvc, httpresponse, openxml-sdk

I have built a basic website for a company where I build a word document(.docx) file dynamically by using a template word doc and content controls and Open XML SDK. Its an ASP.NET MVC 2. I used the same code shown in this link where they build a Sales Contract document using Open XML. You can find it at almost the last section of the page seen in the following link:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469465(v=office.12).aspx

My problem is everything works fine on my development system. But when I host the application on GoDaddy servers and at the end when the Word Document is saved, Microsoft Word says the document is corrupt and has to be recovered.

I saw a similar question in the following link:
[Why are .docx files being corrupted when downloading from an ASP.NET page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477564/why-are-docx-files-being-corrupted-when-downloading-from-an-asp-net-page)

I tried the same and it did not work for me and I get the same error and now I am clueless as to where the error actually is.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.