# Forcing the browser to download a docx file in JAVA generates a corrupted document

Tags: java, ms-office, mime-types, docx, force-download

Using JAVA, I'm trying to force the browser to download files.

Here is the code I currently use:

```java
response.reset();
response.resetBuffer();
response.setContentType(mimeType);
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\"");

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
IOUtils.copy(in, out);

out.flush();
out.close();
in.close();
response.flushBuffer();
```

It works *almost* well, but when forcing the download of a `docx` document (MS Office 2007+), the downloaded file is corrupted (at least, that's what MS Office tells me). If I try to open it directly on the server which stores them, that error doesn't appear, which means that the problem does interfere when downloading (and not when uploading).

According to [IANA](http://www.iana.org/assignments/media-types/application/index.html), the MIME type of such a file should be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document` **(1)**, but specifying that MIME type doesn't resolve the problem.

There are several *tracks* on the Web, but none of them worked for me. There seems to be a [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2477564/why-are-docx-files-being-corrupted-when-downloading-from-an-asp-net-page) in `ASP.NET`, but I didn't find the equivalent in `JAVA`.

I also tried to use the MIME type `application/vnd.ms-word` **(2)** as I saw [there](http://www.coderanch.com/t/468307/JSP/java/pptx-docx), but the downloaded file is still corrupted. Idem for the MIME type `application/msword` **(3)** a guy suggested [here](http://code.google.com/p/java2word/issues/detail?id=16), and for the generic MIME type `application/octet-stream` **(4)** as put forward on [this forum](http://www.coderanch.com/t/572284/Servlets/java/docx-won-open).

Then, for each of these four MIME types, I tried to change the name of the downloaded file from `myfile.docx` to `myfile.doc` (no *x* anymore), but the problem persists.

So, how to force the download of an *uncorrupted-when-downloaded* `docx` file? Is my piece of code correct?

Comment: You must have something that does not work in the servlet returning the file because I have a WebApp that return docX for years and never had any problem downloading the file. You can always rename your *.docx in *.zip and see if the content of the zip file is corrupted or not.

Comment: @GuillaumePolet I just tried renaming the file `myfile.zip`, uploading it and downloading it: the archive isn't corrupted. When re-renaming the downloaded file `myfile.docx`, the problem reappears. Which MIME type did you use? Did you renamed your file from `*.docx` to `*.doc`?

Comment: Content type is set to 'application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document' (without the single quotes). The files ends with .docx. Maybe consider posting your complete code of your servlet doPOst/doGet

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I tried by chance to add more headers, and in fact, the `Content-Length` header resolved the problem...

So finally, I just add this line to make it work:

```
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());
```

Comment: [SO isn't like all those other sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/128554/175248), and it sometimes provokes people for saying that it's a forum.  In either event, I'm glad to hear that you were able to resolve your own problem.  Be sure to mark it solved in ~48 hours' time.

Comment: @sp00m what was your content-type?

Comment: @P-RAD `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Comment: @sp00m thanks for the info , Not able to get it worked . but adding a download attribute in markup worked !!! (http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/links.html)

Comment: @sp00m I could get it working because of the solution suggested by you. Tried a lot of suggestions listed in several stackoverflow questions. Nothing helped, but your answer did. I'm indebted to you, dear programmer!