# Upgrading from .xls to .xlsx with POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have a web application In which i have  excel file(.xls) download option. Now I Have to provide that feature in .xlsx

I am trying to Use POI Jar. When I try to do that as a stand alone Application it works fine, but when I try to integrate that into a web application, I am getting an error as

> Excel Found Unreadable Content in FILENAME.xlsx. do you want to recover the content of this workbook?
>   If you trust the source of this workbook click yes!

```
XSSFWorkbook w = FileName.createExcelWorkbookPosition(
        request.getParameter("BSNS_DT"));
response.setContentType(
        "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment;filename=filename.xlsx");
w.write(response.getOutputStream());
```

Here's the Java code where I create the spreadsheet:

```
public static XSSFWorkbook createExcelWorkbookPosition(String BsnsDate)
    throws Exception
{
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("workbook.xlsx");

    // create a new workbook
    XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
    // create a new sheet
    XSSFSheet s = wb.createSheet();
    // declare a row object reference
    XSSFRow r = null;
    // declare a cell object reference
    XSSFCell c = null;

    // header row and columns
    r = s.createRow(0);
    c = r.createCell(0);
    c.setCellValue("Business Date");    
    //c.setCellStyle(cs);
    c = r.createCell(1);
    c.setCellValue("Account No");

    try {
        wb.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("File writed");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error");
        System.out.println(e);
    }
    return wb;
}
```

Can anyone please help? Sorry for any bad English! Thanks.

Comment: Can you share the code you use to create the excel workbook?

Comment: Can you post some snippet of code to ensure that excel is correctly generated? Do you only changed file extension o change generation too?

Comment: Check this link. http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/excel-found-unreadable-content/d5c54cc7-6290-4f55-86ac-21a65f9bb807. Might help.

Comment: @zeppaman  I have changed the code as well .Please find the Code In edit Post

Comment: I'm sorry, I think we wrote at the same time, please take a look at the link belove.

Comment: I had a quite similar issue, please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/10431317/1225328. The solution was to add the content-length of the response.

Comment: @sp00m I am not able to get The Size of file . Can You Please help me with that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had a quite similar issue, please have a look at [Forcing the browser to download a docx file in JAVA generates a corrupted document](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10431317/1225328). The point was to add the Content-Length header of the response.

Try to make `createExcelWorkbookPosition` returning the file instead of the `XSSFWorkbook`:

```
public static File createExcelWorkbookPosition(String BsnsDate) throws Exception {  
    File file = new File("workbook.xlsx");
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    // ...  
    return file;
}
```

Then:

```
File file = FileName.createExcelWorkbookPosition(request.getParameter("BSNS_DT"));
// ...
response.setContentLength((int) file.length());    

InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
OutputStream out = response.getOutputStream();
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
int len;
while ((len = in.read(buffer)) != -1) {
    out.write(buffer, 0, len);
}
// if using Apache IO, the above code can be simplified to IOUtils.copy(in, out);
// if using Guava, Files.copy(file, out);

// don't forget to close your streams and flush the response buffer
```

Comment: Thanks It worked like a charm.Can you Please tell me is it necessary to Initialize the byte array with 1024 .What if I have too much data .Will it cause me a problem.Thanks a lot For your help .

Comment: @crazyStart This is just the size of the buffer. Have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/8748960/1225328 for more details. And if this answer suited your needs, don't forget to [accept](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5235/186921) it ;)