# Java mail attached file showing corrupt after download

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, inputstream, email-attachments

I am sending a mail with a attachment, But when i am try to open the file, it's not opening and giving following error:

[image]

I try to do it like:

```
JavaMailSenderImpl mailSender = getMailSender();
MimeMessage message = mailSender.createMimeMessage();
MimeMessageHelper helper;
URLDataSource url;
try {
        helper = new MimeMessageHelper(message, true);
        url = new URLDataSource(new URL("localhost:8080/test/attachment/simpldoc.docx"));
        helper.setFrom(mailFrom);
        helper.setSubject(subject);
        helper.setTo(mailTo);
        helper.setText(text, true);
        helper.addAttachment(attachmentName, url);
        mailSender.send(message);
    } 
    catch (MessagingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: Can you open the "details" please?

Comment: How does the URL `localhost:8080/test/attachment/simpldoc.docx` serve the file? Could you post this part as well? Because I had a quite similar error (see [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10432218/1225328)): adding the `ContentLength` of the response solved it.

Comment: try this, helper.addAttachment(attachmentName, new ClassPathResource("attachment/simpldoc.docx"));

Comment: @rpax In details, It says The file is corrupt cannot open.

Comment: You should use File instead of URL to get the attachment.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass a url object as a attachment.

You can use url.getOutputStream() to open stream and then write into a file object before attaching the file.

All of that is bad.

You should be using File to get the relevant file.

so replace

```
URLDataSource url;
//Code
url = new URLDataSource(new URL("localhost:8080/test/attachment/simpldoc.docx"));
```

with

```
File url;
//Code
url = new File("file://localhost:8080/test/attachment/simpldoc.docx")
```

That should return you the actual file and store it in url object.

Give that a go.