# How to implement a desktop download from web form in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

In my website that I am currently working on, I store some images in a folder in the same directory as my .aspx files in the project file. What method can I use to write a code so that when someone clicks an asp:Button, the browser downloads the image (with a given url) for them.

Here is a code example of what it would look like.

```
Protected Sub button_img_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles button_img.Click
    MagicalFunctionDownloadImage("image.jpeg")
End Sub
```

Hope that made sense!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You need to write the file to the response. Here is an example:[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779139/writing-memorystream-to-response-object][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779139/writing-memorystream-to-response-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The asp:button will really be just a hyperlink, and you'll set a url item that corresponds to your image. It will point to a *handler* (***.ashx file) that you build, instead of a page (*.aspx file). The handler works much like a page, but without some of the cruft you won't use, and it will allow to set a few specific headers.  You then use Response.BinaryWrite() to send the file data to the browser:

```
Response.Clear()
Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=<filename here>")
Response.ContentType = "<content/type here>"
Response.BinaryWrite(<path to file or byte array goes here>)
Response.Flush()
Response.End()
```

Comment: Thanks very much for the solution! Can you possibly suggest any implementation as to how to get the size of the image in bytes to create the byte array? I tried 'Dim Buffer(Image.FromFile("image.jpg").Length) As Byte'  but it gave me an error saying FromFile is not a member of Sytem.ExceptionControls.Image (something like that)!