# response.write pptx file forces me to save the file to local disk, I cannot do open only

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a C# asp.net web page to stream a pptx file to the screen.  The first time the page runs, it gives a open file option.  I select open file, the page posts back.  But I am presented only with save or cancel.  The file never opens.  I have to save the file to disk and then open it.  Is there any way to simply open the file the first time?

Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.presentationml.presentation";

```
                    Response.WriteFile("xyz.pptx");
                    Response.End();
```

Comment: It's possible it's a browser issue. Check your browser settings.

Comment: Do you have write access to the folder where the pptx file is located? I'm wondering if it's trying to create the temp file and can't. See the following for more info: http://superuser.com/questions/309057/avoid-powerpoint-word-2010-creating-temporary-files-in-working-directory

Comment: I found an answer from another stack overflow post at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13779139/writing-memorystream-to-response-object.