# Save PDF document to the Response.OutputStream using PDFsharp

Tags: c#, asp.net, pdfsharp

I'm trying to save a copy of the source file directly into a response output stream. But, as a result of this code, the browser window has a dark background. How can I do it without using а MemoryStream?

```
public static void CreateCollage(IEnumerable<Stamp> stamps, Stream input)
{

    using (PdfDocument outDoc = new PdfDocument())
        using (PdfDocument inputDoc = PdfReader.Open(input, PdfDocumentOpenMode.Import))
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < inputDoc.PageCount; i++)
            {
                var page = inputDoc.Pages[i];
                var pageOut = outDoc.AddPage(page);

                foreach (var stamp in stamps.Where(s => s.xyp.page == (i + 1)))
                    InsertData(pageOut, stamp, page.Width.Value, page.Height.Value);
            }
            outDoc.Save(context.Response.OutputStream, true);
        }
}
```

If I use Save() function - I get an error:

> The specified method is not supported.

in System.Web.HttpResponseStream.get_Position()
   in PdfSharp.Pdf.IO.PdfWriter.WriteFileHeader(PdfDocument document) 
in d:\Users\yudina\Desktop\pdfsharp\PDFsharp\src\PdfSharp\Pdf.IO\PdfWriter.cs:row 488

Comment: It seems you have to create a `MemoryStream` because `HttpResponseStream` does not support changing the position in the stream.

Comment: Ok, thanks guys. :(   Too bad..

Comment: This is how you do it completely https://stackoverflow.com/a/21763965/20651

Answer (score 1):

You do not call `outDoc.Close()` and nothing ever gets written into your `OutputStream`.

Comment: So, I can't realize this without a MemoryStream?

Comment: What happens when you call `Close()`? Did you try? You can create a `MemoryStream`, but you still have to call `Close()` or `Save()` or nothing will be written to the stream.