# Run code after HttpHandler has finished executing

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, httphandler, ihttphandler

An HttpHandler is in charge of dispatching file downloads to the end user using `HttpResponse.TransmitFile`. This file needs to be deleted after the download is completed, however if the file is deleted before `HttpResponse.End` then the file is missing and the download fails, and any code after `HttpResponse.End` is not executed.

What would be the best way to delete this file after the download is completed and the `HttpResponse` is ended?

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpResponse r = context.Response;
    string filePath = context.Request.QueryString["filePath"];
    string fName = context.Request.QueryString["fname"];
    r.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=\"" + fName + "\"");
    r.TransmitFile(fullPath);
    r.End();
}
```

Comment: what type of file is it? does it have a specific content-type?

Comment: also, I don't think there is a need to do `HttpResponse.End()` call here, Infact, I see the notion as inhibiting to other `ProcessRequest` scopes and handling that could occur, to include `HttpModule`.  You should potentially just do a `Flush()` call here.

Answer (score 0):

Given your requirement and issue, you should be working with implementations that immediately affect the `HttpResponse.OutputStream` here.

If you look up `HttpResponse.TransmitFile` you'll note that it does not buffer the filestream into memory.

> Writes the specified file directly to an HTTP response output stream, without buffering it in memory.

For your purposes, you do want it buffered into memory; after which, you can delete the file.

---

#### Example Implementation

Actually, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26012588/1366179) to another SO question provides an implementation that is appropriate to handling this:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    string absolutePath = "~/your path";
    //copy to MemoryStream
    using (MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (FileStream fs = File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(absolutePath))) 
        { 
            fs.CopyTo(ms); 
        }
    
        //Delete file
        if(File.Exists(Server.MapPath(absolutePath)))
           File.Delete(Server.MapPath(absolutePath))
    
        //Download file
        context.Response.Clear()
        context.Response.ContentType = "image/jpg";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + absolutePath + "\"");
        context.Response.BinaryWrite(ms.ToArray())
    }
    
    Response.End();
}
```

---

Note that you can write directly to the `HttpResponse.OutputStream` and not use `Write` methods off the `HttpResponse` object:

```
File.OpenRead(Server.MapPath(absolutePath)).CopyTo(context.Response.OutputStream)
```

Comment: regarding the `Write` methods, I think there could be concerns with some of those methods setting properties of `HttpResponse` object, like `Content-Type` and `Content-Length`.  For all of these methods, and specifically to `CopyTo(content.Response.OutputStream)`, you should add/specify appropriate and correct `Content-Length` and `Content-Type` headers as well.

Answer (score -1):

Not entirely sure about this but `.End()` raises the `EndRequest` event, so it might work to add that to your http handler. Hopefully that will be late enough (it's the final event in the pipeline).

```
private void Application_EndRequest(Object source, EventArgs e)
{
    // delete file here.
}
```

Comment: This method doesn't get called

Comment: I believe this is used by a `HttpModule` and not a `HttpHandler`.